# sshfs transform_symlinks is broken

Tags: 11.10, ssh, symbolic-link, sshfs, fuse

I've been using the same fstab command for a while now:

```
sshfs#user@host.be:/home/user /home/user/vps fuse user,port=22,uid=1000,gid=1000,allow_other,reconnect,transform_symlinks 0 0
```

And it used to work fine.

But on 11.10 it doesn't transform symlinks anymore, they're all reported as broken, even though the option is clearly set. What gives?

Comment: maybe this could help: http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/ppk/writings/security/sshfs.html/ and take a look of this http://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/ppk/writings/security/sshfs.html/ssh.html When I try the fuse at the end get "fuse: invalid argument `fuse'". hope this could help a little. =D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The option 'transform_symlinks' does not work anymore, you need 'follow_symlinks' instead.

Comment: `follow_symlinks` still works, but it's not the same thing. It has a very different effect.

Comment: @Albert can you expand on the difference?

Comment: @becko Transform symlinks will transform the symlinks into transformed symlinks. Follow symlinks will follow the symlink instead, i.e. you would not see the symlink at all on the client side but just the content followed by it.

Comment: What does it mean it transforms symlink? If the symlink points to something not under the mounted remote dir, what should I use?